# In a multi-tenant app, the tenant name shows as blank

Tags: abp

In a ABP v4.4 `ApplicationService`, I've got a `using()` block to change to another tenant to perform some actions on a user account inside that tenant.

The tenant change works as it should, the `CurrentTenant` object shows the correct Id, although the `CurrentTenant.Name` property shows a `null` value. Everything else including the user account operations work fine, so it's really just the tenant name not showing, which I need access to in this block.

[image: Debugger showing CurrentTenant object]

In the database, the tenant name value is specified as `MY TENANT` and really shouldn't be `null` when accessed via `CurrentTenant.Name` (screenshot below showing corresponding Tenant Id).

[image: Database row showing Tenant Id and Name]

Any idea what's gone wrong here? The only workaround I can think of here to use `ITenantRepository` to get the value out of the db which feels wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the name when calling `CurrentTenant.Change` if you want it to be set:

```cs
var tenant = await _tenantRepository.GetAsync(Guid.Parse(tenantId));

using (CurrentTenant.Change(tenant.Id, tenant.Name))
{
    var tenantName = CurrentTenant.Name;
    // ...
}
```

`CurrentTenant.Change` simply sets the given `id` and `name` to the current scope:

> ```cs
> public IDisposable Change(Guid? id, string name = null)
> {
>     return SetCurrent(id, name);
> }
>
> private IDisposable SetCurrent(Guid? tenantId, string name = null)
> {
>     var parentScope = _currentTenantAccessor.Current;
>     _currentTenantAccessor.Current = new BasicTenantInfo(tenantId, name);
>     return new DisposeAction(() =>
>     {
>         _currentTenantAccessor.Current = parentScope;
>     });
> }
> ```

Reference: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/9c3b34067524b852c9eaf497728409d6f5e08ec4/framework/src/Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy/Volo/Abp/MultiTenancy/CurrentTenant.cs#L21-L34

Comment: What if I want to change the tenant globally?

Comment: @AHMADEZZAT I suppose it would work without the `using` statement. Please [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you encounter a problem.